# To check whether any of the following is an ideal in the ring of continuous real valued functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, continuity

Let $C(\mathbb R)$ denote the ring of all continuous real valued functions on $\mathbb R$, with the operations of pointwise addition and pointwise multiplication. Which of the following form an ideal in this ring?

A. The set of all $C^{\infty}$ functions with compact support.

B. The set of all continuous functions with compact support.

C. The set of all continuous functions which vanish at infinity, i.e. functions $f$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$.

I could disprove (C) by taking $F(x)= \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and $G(x)=1+x^2$. Clearly $F(x)$ satisfies (C) but $F(x)G(x)$ doesn't.

Rest I am not able to solve.

Answer (score 1):

(A) is not an ideal, because the product of a continous function which isn't $C^{1}$ and a $C^{\infty}$ function is not $C^{\infty}$. (B) is an ideal, because $supp(fg)\subseteq supp(f)\cap supp(g)$.